# PUBG mobile: can you cook grenade?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

I had a tense last circle battle (me and one other person... I happened to win). I wanted to grenade the other guy but I didn't know how to cook the grenade.

**PUBG mobile: can you cook grenade? If yes, how?**

I could have had a perfect no shot kill if I knew how to cook a grenade.

Answer (score 12):

When you have selected the grenade, hold the fire button. A small timer should appear in the center of your screen, showing how long you have left before it explodes. Using that, you can throw it more accurately.
[image]